# Hows this site made: SATandCABLE.com - (I know it's with drupal)

Tags: drupal, shopping-cart, footer, ubercart

The question may seem a bit 'large' or overwelming, so let me explain exactly what  I would like to know; Basically, on the website [SATandCABLE](http://satandcable.com) does anyone have any idea how the shopping cart works...

I admire the way that when you add something to the masket or click the image in the 'footer' that never moves it pops up with the stuff in your basket and your account details; and I would like something similar (if not the same) for my new website, but I have no idea how to do it seen as I'm not a web coder !

I know some of details from the developers website [DavidSlack.co.uk](http://davidslack.co.uk) like it's made using Drupal and Ubercart ( and from  different forums ) but Dave's contact form wasn't working properly when I tried it, so thats I'm asking you guys if you could figure out how he did it?

I'm hoping it's with modules because I haven't *properly* learned php or anything, so if it's not could you give me as much code as possible please?

Thanks in Advance

Andy

Comment: @Ben, hi, i'd like to say thanks but to be honest I can't. I'm not that new to web programming and even if I was that answer isn't very helpful! Why did  you vote my question down? It's a genuine question isn't it? Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @The downvoter: Why? He's trying to learn.

Comment: Thanks Drknezz for sticking up for at least someone understands! Could someone vote me up again and can someone answer my question please? Thanks

Comment: @Andy - I didn't down-voted your question. Now, I did a comment on how I could implement it and probably how they did it.

Comment: Sorry for accusing you Ben, I didn't releasize how actually down voted me. ( Can someone vote my back up again please ! ) I don't want to comment on you answer anymore but thanks anyway. Now, can someone please give me some more information ? - PLEASE :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the shopping cart on that site is implemented fairly awesomely.

From looking at the code on the site, it looks like these will form the backbone of the site, and should have 90% of the site's functionality

- [ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart)
- [ubercart ajax cart](http://drupal.org/project/uc_ajax_cart)
- jQuery update
- CCK
- Content
- FileField
- ImageAPI
- ImageCache
- ImageField
- Lightbox2
- Google Analytics
- Pathauto
- [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)
- [Tagadelic](http://drupal.org/project/tagadelic)
- [Cumulus](http://drupal.org/project/cumulus)
- Poll
- Forum
- [dhtml_menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu)
- [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools)
- [fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar)

The module author for the ajax cart block has an [example site](http://shaque.net/catalog/t-shirts) with a simple implementation

Probably the most work that would be needed to create a clone site would be the theming, as that custom theme looks like it would have taken some time to complete

The site looks like it could use some additional performance related modules though as it is painfully slow, for instance:

- [Boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost)

Hope this helps you get started

Comment: wiifm, I can't thank you enough for that answer it is brilliant and just what I wanted, Thank you. It looks like you've put a lot of effort into for me aswell so thanks again, at least someone cares :) I'm gunna vote you up for that answer

Comment: No worries, I do drupal for a living, more than happy to spread the knowledge

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer for SATandCABLE and it seems you found my site (davidslack.co.uk).

I'll be looking at my contact form tonight which seems fine in in Google Chrome, Firefox, IE9, but not IE8, 7, or 6. I'll sort that tonight. I'm still 'playing' with my site so its up and down. Sorry.

If you contact me tomorrow (or leave a comment) I'll get back to you and see what help I can offer.

The SATandCABLE basket is a simple idea, it's just a div that has a theme region so I can drop blocks in. When the customer clicks the basket or the button at the bottom right a hide/show javascript function is called which hide/shows the basket ID. The whole thing was designed in Fireworks and then the theme created with php and css and that's it.

Hi Wiifm, Unfortunately, I can't use some of the cashing on the site as it messes with the ajax on the basket, but I'll look into the boost module. It would be nice to speed things up :)

Dave.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for joining the discussion. Sorry, I didn't reply sooner, to be honest I didn't expect anymore answers here and I haven't suscribed! Anyway, I'm quite busy actually trying to get my business up and running at the minute, so I may contact you sometime in the future for technical info! At the minute, I'm just making tdo will the left vertical menu, as I'm no web coder and I Actually use Artisteer! Hope you get your things sorted. Andy PS I thought it would be something simple like that (satandcable's cart)